# $y'$ is unbounded on $({\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}},1)$ & $y'$ is bounded on $(1,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, real-numbers

Let $y:({\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}},\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be the solution of $(2x-y)y'+(2y-x)=0;y(1)=3$.Then show that

(A)$y'$ is unbounded on $({\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}},1)$

(B)$y'$ is bounded on $(1,\infty)$

**Solution**

I've solved the IVP and it  is $y(x)=2x+\sqrt{3x^2-2}$

Since $(2x-y)y'+(2y-x)=0$.So, $y'=\frac{x-2y}{2x-y}$

$y'$ will be unbounded in $({\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}},1)$ if in $({\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}},1)$ somehow $2x-y$ becomes zero.I'm not getting how to find the number in $({\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}},1)$ at which $2x-y$ becomes zero.

Please guide me

Answer (score 1):

If $y=2x+\sqrt{3x^2-2}$, then $2x-y=-\sqrt{3x^2-2}$, whch is zero if $x=\sqrt\frac23$. This is outside the domain of $y$, but it means that as $x$ tends to $\sqrt\frac23$ from above, $|y'|=\left |\dfrac{2y-x}{2x-y}\right |$ grows without limit (because the numerator $2y-x$ is $\ge 3x$, which is always $>1$).

Comment: :Thank you...I got this.What about the part (B),can we explicitly have the bound for $y'$?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your solution $y(x)=2x+\sqrt{3x^2-2}$,
$$y'(x)=2+\frac{3x}{\sqrt{3x^2-2}}$$
is unbounded on $(\sqrt{2/3},1)$ because its limit at  $(\sqrt{2/3})^+$ is $\infty$.

It is bounded on $[1,\infty)$ because it is continuous and its limit at $\infty$ is $0$. Or more explicitely: it is positive and decreasing, hence bounded on this interval by $y'(1)=5$.